# Is the word 'append' synonymous with 'insert'?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Append is defined in the [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/append) dictionary to mean:

"*to add (something) to a piece of writing*"

When observing the common usage of the word, it's typically to imply that something was specifically inserted ***after*** something else; after the last chapter, after the last paragraph, etc.

But considering the lexical definition, the word "*append*" really doesn't imply *specifically* where something is being inserted. This is why I feel that it's lexically synonomous to the word "*insert*" but from an every-day usage standpoint, it's not.

Comment: No, *append* specifically means "at the end", even in every day usage. And a doctor could not "append" a hypodermic needle into your arm. The words are fundamentally distinct.

Comment: @DanBron I literally wrote, "but from an every-day usage standpoint, it's not." So, I'm with you on the "every day usage" part... But the lexical definition is what I asked about. If you don't know, lexical means relating to a dictionary.

Comment: I had misinterpreted from which position you were defending the synonymity. And I'll need to go check my dictionary, but I will be quite surprised if it doesn't explicitly call out the notion of "at the end". Dictionaries *record* (every-day) usage, they don't dictate it.

Comment: @DanBron Thank you! Yeah, I checked my dictionary (and online) and couldn't find anything about it specifically saying _where_ content is added.

Comment: Read the "Full Definition" in the link you included!!  It says *1 :  attach, affix. 2 :  to add as a supplement or appendix (as in a book).*  Neither of those definitions implies "insert".

Comment: @HotLicks Neither of those words are defined in a lexical source to mean "after something". Look it up.

Comment: And "append" does not mean "after" or "at the end".  A bracelet can be appended to an arm without being at the end of the arm, or the body.

Comment: @HotLicks Ah! Exactly what I was looking for. The answer to my question is definitely, "no" then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Append](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/append), strictly speaking, denotes something added on.

> 1. To add as a supplement or appendix: *appended a list of errors to the report.*
> 2. To fix to; attach: *append a charm to the bracelet.* (AHDEL/TFD)

It comes from the Latin, *ad* + *pendere*, to *hang to*, and has carried that meaning since the late 1300's.

[Insert](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=insert) entered English a little bit later, but carries no particular location (except *perhaps* not "at the end".) Again from Latin, *in* meaning *into, in, on, upon* + "serere", *attach, join, arrange, line up*.

The fact that in English, we're familiar with appendices (usually at the end of a book/other) gives it a connotation of being at the end, but it's really not; our arms are appendages (they are attached to our bodies), the appendix is a little appendage from the colon, etc. *Pendants* (from the same root) simply hang. *Pending* means hanging...

The words may be very similar, but I wouldn't consider them to be exact synonyms.

Comment: Yes, true. But even with that broader definition, it is *not* synonymous with "insert", because appendages "stick out", they don't "come between". And, of course, texts being two-dimensional (or even one-dimensional) runs of letters only offer two places for things to "stick out": before the "main body" or "after". There is no "left" or "right" or "back" or "front". And in the context of texts, even "before" is barred: text can only be *appended* at the end. By contrast, it can be *inserted* anywhere. Bottom line: no, the words are not synonymous, "lexically" or any other way.

Answer (score 2):

It’s my impression/vague recollection that, until about 30 or 35 years ago,
“append” meant “attach to [the outside of] something;
i.e., attach at a boundary (typically the beginning or the end,
if applicable)”. 
(So I believe that the words “append” and “insert” have been mutually exclusive,
in common parlance, for my entire life.) 
“Append” may have had the connotation “attach *at the end*”
because of words like “appendix”,
but I believe that that was only the most common usage,
and not the sole definition.

And then computers (and, in particular, Unix) appeared,
and the phrase [“append to a file”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=append+to+a+file&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cappend%20to%20a%20file%3B%2Cc0), appearing around 1974,
caused the term “append” to come to *mean* “attach at the end”. 
I believe that this shift in the meaning of the word “append”
is responsible for the birth of the word [“prepend”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprepend%3B%2Cc0) around the year 1980. 
I suspect that the computer terminology is also responsible
for the uptick in the use of [“append”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepend%2Cappend&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprepend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappend%3B%2Cc0) starting in the late 1970s,
after a long period of decline.  Even so,
“append” is used nearly an order of magnitude less often than [“attach”](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=prepend%2Cappend%2Cattach&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cprepend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cappend%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cattach%3B%2Cc0).

Since Unix may be a factor in this,
I should probably point out that the Unix text editors
(`vi` and its ancestor `ed`)
support *inserting* before any character and *appending* after any character. 
While this seems to cement the idea that you cannot append to the beginning,
it has the side-effect that you can insert (inject?) text
into the interior of a file
with either the **`i`** command or the **`a`** command.

Answer (score 0):

They are not identical. "Append" means to add something after a main writing. "Insert" means to introduce or interpolate something into a writing.The word "[appendage](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/appendage)" should help with the understanding that the object in question is added to a main body.

In a writing, the "appendix" always follows the main text.

**[Append](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/append)**

1
:  attach, affix

2
:  to add as a supplement or appendix (as in a book)

Source: Merriam-Webster [Unable to post link]

**Insert**

2
:  to put or introduce into the body of something :  interpolate

[Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/insert)

Comment: I am unable at this time to post more than two links.  They system barred me.

Comment: The lexical definition of _attach_ or _affix_ does **not** say anything about it being _after_. This is my point...

Comment: It says "to add as a supplement" or an "appendix".  Those only follow the main writing.  And "interpolate", which can be used to define "insert" means to add into an existing body, never to add to the end of it.

Comment: @zeugma If you add a comment noting what other links you'd like to add, and where you'd like to add them (i.e. location & anchor text), I will edit them in for you. The link limit is imposed to dissuade spam, but it often poses a barrier to legitimate users as well.

Comment: @DanBron:  Thank you.  Please link this URL to "append."  http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/append

Comment: @8protons: I looked up "lexical" at Merriam-Webster. The definition there was not helpful. But logically, "append" and "insert" are quite different, and it is more than a matter of common usage.

Comment: @zeugma "Lexical" is a term I learned from a logic class because when debating with people, it's common to get lost in everyone's own personal definition of things; which I honestly don't care about for this question. So you use the word "lexical" to establish that you're using a dictionary or defined language source. Lexical - "relating to or of the nature of a lexicon or dictionary."

Comment: @8protons In any event, the two terms are not synonymous. I have not been using a personal, idiosyncratic, definition, I have been citing a major American dictionary. In no way do the two words signify the same concept.